# Inequality for derived set

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $X$ and a subset $S$ of $X$, in Kuratowsky 1966 (volume 1, page 76) there is the inequality
$$
S''\subseteq S'\tag{*}
$$
in wikipedia there is the inequality
$$
S''\subseteq S'\cup S\tag{**}
$$
(which does not exclude (*))
and in the talk behind the web page there is this example proving (*) wrong. $X=\{a,b\}$, $S=\{a\}$, $S'=\{b\}$, $S''=\{a\}$.
$a\notin S'$ because all the intersections with a neighborhood of $a$ (only $X$) contain no other point than $x$ itself.

> Could someone shed some light on this inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kuratowski assumes all spaces are $T_1$. The counterexample is not $T_1$.

My French edition has (first chapter, paragraph 4, système d'axiomes)

> II) si $X$ ne contient qu'un seul point ou n'en contient aucun, on a $\overline{X}=X$.

(If $X$ has only one point, or none at all, we have $\overline{X} =X$), so a space has all singletons closed, so the space is $T_1$ in modern terms.

Comment: Right after reading your answer, I remembered that he assumed $T_1$ if not otherwise stated. He calls it Axiom (5) but he also use the term $T_1$.  English edition p. 38 (the first page on topology). Thank you.

Comment: @PeptideChain Glad to help. I know that derived sets only behave nicely in $T_1$ spaces, and I vaguely recalled Kuratowski's axioms including it, so I looked it up. Et voilà!

Comment: I had to recheck everything. The result is that most of the formula on $S'$ are valid only with $T_1$, as you said. Now Kelley 1955 write on p. 41: Theorem 5: A subset of a topological space is closed if and only if it contains the set of its accumulation points. Which is in general wrong: $\tau=\{\varnothing,\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$, $S=\{a\}$, $S'=\{b\}$, thus $S$ is closed but $S'\nsubseteq S$.

Comment: ...and I do not see any mention of $T_1$. The theorem is just on the 5th page on topology.

Comment: @PeptideChain accumulation point in Kelley is not limit point in Kuratowski.

Comment: disconcerting! Thank you.

Comment: @PeptideChain $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ iff every (open) neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$. In all spaces the closure of $A$ is the set of its accumulation points.